# Need to login many times before pantheon starts ( problem after installing xfce)

Tags: release-loki, greeter, pantheon

I installed XFCE on top of elementary os to help me transition to pantheon. However, now that I'm ready to fully switch to this beautiful desktop environment I realized that I need to restart lightdm and login a couple of times before the DE actually starts.

Other info that might be useful is that I am using an external monitor connected with a VGA cable to my laptop (hp probook g4), but I would like to learn how I can track down what's going on and be able to try to fix it myself or at least post a meaningful log here.

Anyhow, I think it's just a matter of resetting a few configurations somewhere but don't know which ones. Sorry for the noob question.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve my own problem, in the end. Basically XFCE had nothing to do with it and I was just not waiting enough time for the desktop to show (see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1599110/)), hence re-logging in multiple times was working after a while because the desktop environment had enough time to be ready. After realizing this, [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/7t5j79/logging_in_takes_24_mintutes/) on reddit helped with solving that problem.